# Data Error for data type Number in Crystal Reports Enterprise

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I am developing a report in SAP Crystal Reports for Enterprise with SQL Command as Data Source, and I run into this weird error, where my data displayed does not match  with whats in the database.  And this happens only to those columns whose datatype is "Number".  When I convert the datatype to String(using to_char) in the command, it displays correctly, but that's not an option for us, because we have to convert around 20 reports.
This command used to work fine for Crystal reports 2011.

**Desired Output**

[image]

**Actual Output**

[image]

Images are from my original support thread here:
http://scn.sap.com/thread/3706675

Any Ideas? Your help is appreciated.

This is my Enterprise Version:
Version : 14.1.2.1121
Build :  2013 Support Pack 2

Thanks
Sunil